# SOAP V2 returns HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: magento-1, api, soap, soap-api-v2

When I add `/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1` to the url I get:

```
This page isn’t working

local.example.en is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

With dev mode and error messages enabled I get this instead:

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /var/www/public/app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Wsdl/Config/Element.php on line 235
```

But `/api/soap/?wsdl` works fine.

WS-I Compliance is set to "Yes" in Magento backend.

exception.log has this message (Ebizmarts/SagePaySuite is not my module):

```
exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML' in /var/www/public/app/code/local/Ebizmarts/SagePaySuite/Model/Feed/Updates.php:35
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/public/app/code/local/Ebizmarts/SagePaySuite/Model/Feed/Updates.php(35): SimpleXMLElement->__construct('<html>??<head><...')
#1 /var/www/public/app/code/local/Ebizmarts/SagePaySuite/Model/Feed/Updates.php(101): Ebizmarts_SagePaySuite_Model_Feed_Updates->getFeedData('http://store.eb...')
#2 /var/www/public/app/code/local/Ebizmarts/SagePaySuite/Model/Feed/Updates.php(90): Ebizmarts_SagePaySuite_Model_Feed_Updates->_getUpdates('Ebizmarts_SageP...')
#3 /var/www/public/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1339): Ebizmarts_SagePaySuite_Model_Feed_Updates->check(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#4 /var/www/public/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1312): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Ebizmarts_SagePaySuite_Model_Feed_Updates), 'check', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#5 /var/www/public/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#6 /var/www/public/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(531): Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#7 /var/www/public/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(160): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->preDispatch()
#8 /var/www/public/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(407): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->preDispatch()
#9 /var/www/public/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#10 /var/www/public/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#11 /var/www/public/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#12 /var/www/public/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#13 /var/www/public/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#14 {main}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things that you should check. I assume that your server/environment is fast enough.

1. Make sure that you've enabled the cache (`System -> Cache Management`)
2. Make sure you've turned on WSDL caching (`System -> Configuration -> Magento Core Api -> Enable WSDL Cache`)
3. Pay attention to Alan Storm's issue which he described at: 
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14822866/magento-soap-api-working-locally-but-not-remotely#14823827

If nothing help, try to increase ***maximum execution time*** in ***php.ini***, at least to be sure that it's working at all. http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: I set max_execution_time to 180 in php.ini and it worked.